# Making UART between ATmega32A and the PC :

Tags: avr, uart

I used PL2303hx to connect my PC to the chip and I did the correct connections and installed the driver of the IC and the program I wrote was simulated succesfully on proteus:
But when I do it on the reality the blue LED in PL2303hx blinks every time I send data from the chip to my PC (e.g. if I make the delay time 1 second it blinks each 1 second )but data is displayed is just <0>

the code to just make sure that it works fine :

```
#define F_CPU 16000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint16_t UBRR_Value = 103; 

    UBRRL = (uint8_t) UBRR_Value; 
    UBRRH = (uint8_t) (UBRR_Value >>8); 
    UCSRB |= (1<<RXEN) | (1<<TXEN); 
    UCSRC |= (3<<UCSZ0);  

    while (1)
    {
        while (! (UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));
        UDR = 'B';
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
    return(0); 
}
```

and the fuse bits `CKSEL` and `CKPOT` are set to fit with 16MHz external crystal just like written in the code. 
[image]

Comment: Is there H/W loopback to enable DTR etc?

Comment: Try verifying the USB interface separately from the AVR. Without the AVR connected to the PL2303, connect RX to TX directly at the PL2303. Use a simple terminal program, like Putty, to send characters to the PL2303...are they sent back to you?

Comment: @ Elliot Alderson  thanks for your comment The problem got solved .. yet Putty is a very powerful software I liked it

Answer (score 0):

Emulators are not same as real world and may not be correctly made. In some AVRs like the ATMega32A, the UBRRH and UCSRC registers are accessed through same address, so you have the wrong sequence to access them. Please read the datasheet section about how to use the registers properly. Basically, don't do a read-modify-write operation to UCSRC, as reading it will actually read UBRRH first, and a second read will read UCSRC. And when writing, use the URSEL bit correctly to select between UBRRH and UCSRC. Basically what happens now is that you set the UBRRH register to non-zero value and thus the baud rate not 9600 but something really slow (about 609 BPS) which the PC interprets as receiving 0 with FRAMING ERROR as seen in the screen shot.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but it was A matter of code segment 
#define BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALLER (((F_CPU / (BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

Comment: Maybe you changed something else as well. That still makes baud rate divisor of 103 like in the original code so it was not the problem.

Comment: it's in the UL and I can't figure why 
UL is just what I changed 
I think this is a C type thing

Comment: Because on AVRs int type is 16 bits and long int type is 32 bits. 9600*16 does not fit to int so you need the type to be UL. But as you did not originally post that part of the code, how could we see the error.

Comment: I posted uint16_t UBRR_Value = 103 ;
And you thought I used the registers in a wrong way 
I didn't mislead anyone here , I just searched the internet for A similar code , 
Why so defensive ?

Comment: UL stands for Unsigned Long and long can store real values like float :'D

Comment: Calculating 103 differently can't have fixed the code by itself, it must be something else in the code like how you use it later. As only you now know the answer, can you please post your working code if it works now, as whatever fixed it would be the answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: No, unsigned long can't store floating point numbers, only integers. Float and double are floating point types that can.

Comment: #define F_CPU 16000000
#define BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALLER (((F_CPU / (BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)


#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{
 UBRRH = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER>>8);
 UBRRL = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER);
 UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
 UCSRC = (1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<URSEL);
 while(1)
 {
  while(!(UCSRA &(1<<UDRE))) ;
  UDR =  'A' ;
  _delay_ms(1000) ;

  
 }
 return(0) ;
 
}

Comment: I am afraid, the problem was using the registers correctly. Code you just posted uses UCSRC register correctly, with URSEL and without read-modify-write operation. So it most definitely was the issue. Not using UL in baud rate calculation.

Comment: Sounds legit
Thanks for your patience 
I've tried removing UL from the code and the output wasn't A It was ▒ instead

Comment: Yes, because without UL the calculation result of the macro is not 103, so baud rate will be wrong. But at least the registers are accessed in a proper way to write the UBRRH and UCSRC. These are two separate things. You need to have correct value for baud rate registers, either by complex macro calculation or just setting it to 103 like you had before in your own code. And you need to write it correctly, which was your original problem and copypasted code has this correct.